# Adding EventHandler to formsfx Field

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I`m using [formsfx](https://github.com/dlemmermann/formsfx) and i got a hang of it, however i dont know how to use 
.addEvent handler to field.

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType());

        }
    };



Field.ofDoubleType(model.priceProperty())
                                    .label("price")
                                    .required("cant be empty")
                                    .addEventHandler(handler).
```

then i get message

```
addEventHandler
(javafx.event.EventType<com.dlsc.formsfx.model.event.FieldEvent>,
EventHandler<? super FieldEvent>)
in Field cannot be applied
to
(javafx.event.EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>)
```

after i tried to use same field event, but no luck, i am missing something, i just dont know what.
Description says it accepts FieldEvent Type and event Handler.

Comment: When you say, "_after i tried to use same field event, but no luck_", what exactly went wrong? Another compilation error? The code didn't do what you want? What is this event handler supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field.ofDoubleType returns a Field, which is a wrapper to contents that are rendered. The actual node that is rendered on sceneGraph is field.getRenderer(). Unfortunately this is not the actual control you want to deal with. It is again a wrapper(GridPane) of all the required stuff for your form control (textfield, choicebox, checkbox, etc).

The getRenderer() returns SimpleControl and there is not standard API to return the exact form control. For example SimpleTextControl contains TextField, TextArea & Label as its  children and the appropriate node is rendered in scenegraph based on context.

For this reason, it is very hard to set the handler on the exact node. (because of lack of API)

So the only node which you have access is the renderer (the GridPane). You can try setting the handlers to this GridPane. But it wont work in most cases because, most default controls consume the events in the handlers.

One way to fix your issue is, instead of handler you can rely on filters. Setting a filter on the GridPane will let you know to listen to appropriate events.

So you can try the below code:

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType());

        }
    };

Field priceField = Field.ofDoubleType(model.priceProperty())
                                    .label("price")
                                    .required("cant be empty"); 

priceField.getRenderer().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
```

**UPDATE :** DemoModel.java of formsfx demo code.

```
package com.dlsc.formsfx.demo.model;

import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.structure.Field;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.structure.Form;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.structure.Group;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.structure.Section;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.util.ResourceBundleService;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.validators.DoubleRangeValidator;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.validators.IntegerRangeValidator;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.validators.RegexValidator;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.model.validators.StringLengthValidator;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.view.controls.SimpleCheckBoxControl;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.view.controls.SimpleRadioButtonControl;
import com.dlsc.formsfx.view.util.ColSpan;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 * This class is used to create the form and holds all the necessary data. This
 * class acts as a singleton where the current instance is available using
 * {@code getInstance}.
 *
 * @author Sacha Schmid
 * @author Rinesch Murugathas
 */
public final class DemoModel {

    private Country country = new Country();

    /**
     * These are the resource bundles for german and english.
     */
    private ResourceBundle rbDE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("demo-locale", new Locale("de", "CH"));
    private ResourceBundle rbEN = ResourceBundle.getBundle("demo-locale", new Locale("en", "UK"));

    /**
     * The default locale is English, thus the {@code ResourceBundleService} is
     * initialised with it.
     */
    private ResourceBundleService rbs = new ResourceBundleService(rbEN);

    private Form formInstance;

    /**
     * Creates or simply returns to form singleton instance.
     *
     * @return Returns the form instance.
     */
    public Form getFormInstance() {
        if (formInstance == null) {
            createForm();
        }

        return formInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new form instance with the required information.
     */
    private void createForm() {
        EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = event -> System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType());
        Field field = Field.ofStringType(country.nameProperty())
                .label("country_label")
                .placeholder("country_placeholder")
                .required("required_error_message")
                .validate(StringLengthValidator.atLeast(2, "country_error_message"));
        field.getRenderer().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,handler);
        formInstance = Form.of(
                Group.of(
                        field,
                        Field.ofStringType(country.isoProperty())
                                .label("ISO_3166_label")
                                .placeholder("ISO_3166_placeholder")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(2, "ISO_3166_error_message")),
                        Field.ofBooleanType(country.independenceProperty())
                                .label("independent_label")
                                .required("required_error_message"),
                        Field.ofDate(country.getIndependenceDay())
                                .label("independent_since_label")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .placeholder("independent_since_placeholder")
                ),
                Section.of(
                        Field.ofStringType(country.currencyShortProperty())
                                .label("currency_label")
                                .placeholder("currency_placeholder")
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(3, "currency_error_message"))
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF),
                        Field.ofStringType(country.currencyLongProperty())
                                .label("currency_long_label")
                                .placeholder("currency_long_placeholder")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF),
                        Field.ofDoubleType(country.areaProperty())
                                .label("area_label")
                                .format("format_error_message")
                                .placeholder("area_placeholder")
                                .validate(DoubleRangeValidator.atLeast(1, "area_error_message"))
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF),
                        Field.ofStringType(country.tldProperty())
                                .label("internet_TLD_label")
                                .placeholder("internet_TLD_placeholder")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(
                                        StringLengthValidator.exactly(3, "internet_TLD_error_message"),
                                        RegexValidator.forPattern("^.[a-z]{2}$", "internet_TLD_format_error_message")
                                ),
                        Field.ofStringType(country.dateFormatProperty())
                                .label("date_format_label")
                                .placeholder("date_format_placeholder")
                                .multiline(true)
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.atLeast(8, "date_format_error_message")),
                        Field.ofSingleSelectionType(country.allSidesProperty(), country.driverSideProperty())
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .label("driving_label")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .render(new SimpleRadioButtonControl<>()),
                        Field.ofStringType(country.timeZoneProperty())
                                .label("time_zone_label")
                                .placeholder("time_zone_placeholder")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(3, "time_zone_error_message")),
                        Field.ofStringType(country.summerTimeZoneProperty())
                                .label("summer_time_zone_label")
                                .placeholder("summer_time_zone_placeholder")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.atLeast(3, "summer_time_zone_error_message"))
                ).title("other_information_label"),
                Section.of(
                        Field.ofSingleSelectionType(country.allCapitalsProperty(), country.capitalProperty())
                                .label("capital_label")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .tooltip("capital_tooltip")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF),
                        Field.ofIntegerType(country.populationProperty())
                                .label("population_label")
                                .format("format_error_message")
                                .placeholder("population_placeholder")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(IntegerRangeValidator.atLeast(1, "population_error_message")),
                        Field.ofMultiSelectionType(country.allContinentsProperty(), country.continentsProperty())
                                .label("continent_label")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .render(new SimpleCheckBoxControl<>()),
                        Field.ofMultiSelectionType(country.allCitiesProperty(), country.germanCitiesProperty())
                                .label("german_cities_label")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF),
                        Field.ofPasswordType("secret")
                                .label("secret_label")
                                .required("required_error_message")
                                .span(ColSpan.HALF)
                                .validate(StringLengthValidator.between(1, 10, "secret_error_message"))
                ).title("cities_and_population_label")
        ).title("form_label")
                .i18n(rbs);

    }

    /**
     * Sets the locale of the form.
     *
     * @param language The language identifier for the new locale. Either DE or EN.
     */
    public void translate(String language) {
        switch (language) {
            case "EN":
                rbs.changeLocale(rbEN);
                break;
            case "DE":
                rbs.changeLocale(rbDE);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid locale");
        }
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting, however did you noticed that every time event get`s triggered 2 times ?
I used your code, and generated form, put form in to renderer, but every time when i press button i get 
Handling event KEY_PRESSED
Handling event KEY_PRESSED, and the source is also the same, its grid pane

Comment: Have you verified whether you are creating multiple fields or setting multiple handlers. Because I checked in the demo code (formsfx demo source) and it is firing only one time. I just updated the DemoModel.java of formsfx demo code for your reference.

Comment: you are right, i did made a mistake in my code, it works as you said ! Thank you very much for detailed answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
model.priceProperty().addListener(event -> {
    //your code here
});
```